# Is WhatsApp end-to-end encryption applied to images?

Tags: whatsapp, end-to-end-encryption

I know that for text, WhatsApp messages are encrypted in a way no "man in the middle" could read them. But what about images?

Imagine you received some private image on your smartphone. Then you open WhatsApp Web on your PC, which uses an employer VPN.

Would the employer be able to "download" the image your Whatsapp Web just loaded?

Comment: See [this answer from CryptoSE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/58444/45423).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [WhatsApp's official FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28030015/), yes.

> Privacy and security is in our DNA, which is why we have end-to-end encryption. When end-to-end encrypted, your messages, photos, videos, voice messages, documents, status updates and calls are secured from falling into the wrong hands.

- The WhatsApp FAQ

This would make sense since the underlying Signal Protocol does not discriminate between images or plaintext, so there is no technical reason to send images in the clear.

However, once the content is on your PC it's stored in plaintext, so if your employer has any monitoring software installed on your PC (or the PC of the person you're talking to) they can view the messages/images there.

For more information on when/how media sent through WhatsApp can be insecure, check out this investigation by The Verge: https://www.theverge.com/2019/7/15/20692184/whatsapp-telegram-media-files-android-messaging-encryption